# Using eval exec with an executable name containing spaces in the path

Tags: tcl, exec, eval

I came across this scenario, where I have to execute `tshark` for decoding the `pcap` file.

Location of of tshark is `C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe`

```
% set fileName TestTShark.pcap
TestTShark.pcap
% set sTsharkCmd "-r $fileName  -Tfields -e ip.src"
-r TestTShark.pcap  -Tfields -e ip.src
% set tsharkPath "C:/Program Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe"
C:/Program Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe
% eval exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
couldn't execute "C:\Program": no such file or directory
% exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
tshark: The file " TestTShark.pcap  -Tfields -e ip.src" doesn't exist.
% set tsharkPath "C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe"
C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe
% exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
tshark: The file " TestTShark.pcap  -Tfields -e ip.src" doesn't exist.
% eval exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
couldn't execute "C:Program": no such file or directory
```

Since the path containing a space, while evaluating the code, `Tcl` treating `C:\Program` as a program name and throwing the error. Then I managed to escape the space with backslash as follows, which worked then.

```
%  set tsharkPath "C:/Program\\ Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe"
C:/Program\ Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe
% eval exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
% type packet.log
20.0.0.5
%
```

I am just curious. Is there any other option to handle this scenario ? Same problem observed with `{*}` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're wanting space to be a part of an argument taken from variable, but to separate arguments coming from another argument. Tcl by default will try to apply the same uniform rules to *all* arguments: you need to do something extra to change that.

**You want to use *expansion* of an argument.** Your command

```
% eval exec $tsharkPath $sTsharkCmd > packet.log
```

Should be written as:

```
% exec $tsharkPath {*}$sTsharkCmd > packet.log
```

See how it is shorter? It's safer too. Try to avoid `eval` unless you really are doing something very complicated. (I hardly ever need it in my code…)

---

If you're stuck with an ancient version of Tcl without `{*}`, you need to do this instead:

```
% eval [linsert $sTsharkCmd 0 exec $tsharkPath > packet.log]
```

Which is horribly non-obvious, or this:

```
% eval {exec $tsharkPath} $sTsharkCmd {> packet.log}
```

Which isn't too nice either (and it's easy to forget to get it quoted right).

Answer (score 1):

```
eval [list exec $tsharkPath {*}$sTsharkCmd]
```

Make the new command to evaluate with the `sTsharkCmd` attributes separated...